# showDialog not visible when I come into the foreground from the background flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I am doing a push notification on my flutter app, handling it both on foreground and background. When the notification is tapped, I want to load a `dialog` before the network operation is fully loaded. So, when I am on the foreground, the dialog shows quite alright but doesn't appear when I come into the foreground from the background. What could be the cause of this?

```
  void showRideOrder(String newOrder) async {
    orderIdString = orderId = newOrder;
    print("new order here" + orderId);
    print("fetching info");
    assetsAudioPlayer.open(
      Audio('sounds/alert.mp3'),
    );
    assetsAudioPlayer.play();
  
   showDialog( //not showing when coming in from the background
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext builder_context) =>
          CustomProgressDialog(status:'Fetching details',),);

    Provider.of<MainBloc>(context, listen: false).
    fetchRideInfo(context, orderId).then((value){
      print("ride order fetched. closing dialog");
     Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
            RideRequestPage(orderId: orderId)),
      );
      orderIdString =null;
    }).catchError((error) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      AlertManager.showToast(error.toString());
    });
    orderIdString = null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because when to come to foreground, the method is not called.

Try extending class with WidgetsBindingObserver and overriding

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    showRideOrder(...);   //call your function
  }
```

Make sure you write switch case and call it in appropriate case